# Ubuntu Server Installation - Bad Archive Mirror

Tags: wireless, server

I am trying to install Ubuntu Server on my desktop computer that has a wireless card. Installing Ubuntu from a flashdrive, I reached a part where I had to remove my wireless card to go through the network part of the installation because it would hang if the card was still inserted. However, I cannot get past the mirror selection. I get an error when it trys to connect to the archive mirror. Obviously, since I don't have my card inserted, it won't connect to anything. But the installation will hang if the cad is inserted. What do I do?